# How can I filter POST numeric values in php?

Tags: php

Numeric values..

```
$price = $_POST['price'];
$zipcode = $_POST['zipcode'];
```

How can I filter two fields passing through a single select tag field called category_id that uses the explode() to recieve the values from this  category_id field.

Form

```
    <?php echo '<label for="Category">Category:</label>
<select name="category_id" size="1" ><br />';


$sql = "SELECT id, name FROM category ORDER BY name";

$rs = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
echo "<option value=\"".$row['name']."$".$row['id']."\">".$row['name']."</option>\n  ";
}


echo '</select>';
```

the way I receive the category_id field with explode but don't know how to filter it since it is a numeric and data field at the same time.

```
$option = explode("$", $_POST['category_id']); 

enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just trying to retrieve the category name and ID from the posted, `$` delimited `category_id` field?

If so, then this should do it

```
$option = explode("$", $_POST['category_id']);
$name = $option[0];
$id   = $option[1];
```

I would be more inclined to just set the ID in the `<option>` `value` attribute and fetch the name from the database or a pre-fetched associative array.

### Update

If you're wanting to validate that field, you could try something like

```
if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\$\d+$/', $_POST['category_id'])) {
    // not valid
}
```

I wouldn't attempt to filter out invalid characters on that field. Validation and error conditions are more concise.

Comment: not retrive but filter those fields like here $itemname = preg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $_POST['item']); if you see the field name is filter with preg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]" in this case item is a text field I was wondering how can I do with the fields above which are numerics and mixed numerics and text in the $option variable with the category_id field

Comment: thank you, your code will filter and validate it at the same time. I was wondering since I have to explode it to use preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]\$\d$/',explode("$", $_POST['category_id']))

Comment: Phil I got an error preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in since the second parameter "name" it is an string it seem that this filtering it only valid to the "id" parameter which is a numeric value. at this point I am thinking to filter it separately similar to Starx approach what do you think?

Comment: i saw the pattern I will test it now where did you got that pattern from ?

Comment: @user oops, forget to allow multiple characters. Fixed now

Comment: a off topic question can I submit a picture file and other text fields within one form?

Comment: @user Yes. Files may be uploaded using a `<input type="file">` element. Your form must have the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute. See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, If i got you correctly. If you are trying to receive the name and id of the product from the same select box, using your technique

```
echo "<option value=\"".$row['name']."$".$row['id']."\">".$row['name']."</option>\n  ";
```

Change this line to this. Just replace `$` with "_" for simplicty

```
echo "<option value=\"".$row['name']."_".$row['id']."\">".$row['name']."</option>\n  ";
```

Then while processing it

```
$category_id = $_POST['category_id'];
$carr = explode("_",$category_id);
$category = $carr[0];
$id = $carr[1];

//now verify them
if((int)$id>0) { //id is valid number
// and so on
```

Comment: And to filter Mr. starx would you filter at this point $category_id = $_POST['category_id'];
 or each individually? $category = $carr[0];
$id = $carr[1];

Comment: Phil I got an error preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in since the second parameter "name" it is an string it seem that this filtering it only valid to the "id" parameter which is a numeric value. at this point I am thinking to filter it separately similar as I said before. This is comment applies to Phil approach as well

Comment: It depends... if I was verifying a pattern, then I would go with what you asked on @Phil's answer, but not in this case, because the pattern is already fixed by you, hard coded on the markup. If you trying to protect against any biased moves by a cracker then such things might be of concerned but still depends....

Comment: from what I am reading preg_replace since to be for string fields and data types

Comment: No, user841823. It matches a regular expression and replaces the matches with what you provide.

Comment: ok, and for the price and zipcode should be a easy regular expression 0-9 it is only expecting number cna you point to a reference where I can find a filtering for this two numerics field as a different from category_id